How to fix the vulnerability - "Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in micromatch"
I am new with JS coding. My website has Next JS framework.
My package.json file looks like the following
dependencies": {
    "@azure/communication-email": "1.0.0",
    "@azure/identity": "4.4.1",
    "@next/third-parties": "14.2.6",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "0.4.4",
    "@types/lodash": "4.17.7",
    "@types/node": "20.4.2",
    "@types/react": "18.3.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.20",
    "date-fns": "3.6.0",
    "disposable-email-domains": "1.0.62",
    "dom-parser": "1.1.5",
    "dotenv": "16.4.5",
    "html-react-parser": "4.2.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "next": "14.2.13",
    "postcss": "8.4.41",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-datepicker": "7.3.0",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "sharp": "0.33.5",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.10",
    "typescript": "5.5.4",
    "valibot": "0.38.0"
  },

When I run yarn audit command it shows me 12 moderate vulnerabilities all in relevance to
Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) in micromatch

How to fix this vulnerability? I cannot see any dependency called micromatch. what do I need to do?

As you can see in the output, micromatch is installed because it is a dependency of lint-staged, which you probably have as a devDependency.
Since the latest version of lint-staged uses micromatch@4.0.8, you are probably using an old version of lint-staged. So upgrading lint-staged should fix the warning.
See also this article
